# Transforming Member Code Number to Known String?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, automapper

I'm migrating data from a legacy system to a newer platform.

The legacy system refers to entity types as number
E.g "Person" could have a type (1, 2 ,3 4) which corresponds to them being a butcher/baker/candlestick maker etc.

```
Person
{
    Type: 1
}
```

The new system will store this type as an actual string value, i.e 
"Butcher", "Baker" etc.

```
Person
{
     Type: "Butcher"
}
```

There's no table that has these values to join on, so I need to transform them accordingly. I was thinking I could use some sort of static dictionary somewhere like:

```
Dictionary<int,string> KnownPeopleTypes ({1, "Butcher"},{2, "Baker"}) etc..
```

But I feel like this is perhaps the wrong way to go about it. Maybe I don't know what to search for, but what is the more "correct" or eloquent way to achieve this with entity framework and/or automapper?

Thanks all.

Comment: Also if you are using enums, might as well store the `enum` in the Dictionary `Dictionary<Person,string>`

Comment: With AM you need a rule. You can apply a resolver for all int properties named "Type" for example. ForAllPropertyMaps does that.

Comment: I'd consider using an enum, with a `DescriptionAttribute` on each entry. Then you can create a `Dictionary` based on the enum.